# htaccess with questionmark

Tags: .htaccess

I have url

http://www.domain.com/folder/?variable=1

i would like to do a mod redirect to index.cfm with the folder going in as path variable and the variable as the second variable.. the first three lines work with my site, i am having trouble with the last bit

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.cfm?path=$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)\?(.*)$ /index.cfm?path=$1&$2 [L]
```

thanks

Comment: The first `rewriterule` will match everything - have you tried reordering them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `QSA` (or `qsappend`) flag, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.cfm?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will make mod-rewrite append any original query-string to the sub-request.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems redirecting a URL with a `?` in it.

The url was like: `/index/slug_with_questionmark?.html`

The solution that works for me:

```
RewriteRule ^index/slug_with_questionmark(.*) http://yourdomain.com/newurl? [R=301,L]
```

Pay attention to the `?` at the second statement. This one fools the browser so it redirects it nicely.